# Python Code for function to Delete a node in a LinkedList

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to write a function that searches for the first node with the value provided as a parameter and deletes the corresponding node from a linked list.

- **Here is what I tried:**

```
 def delete(self, value):
        """Delete the first node with a given value."""
        temp = self.head
        while(temp.next.self.value != self.value):
            temp = temp.next
        ptr = temp.next
        temp.next = temp.next.next
        #delete ptr
        return temp
```

- **Here's What I expect:**

First I had a local variable temp storing value of self.head (this means temp point to the first node)
Next, I tried to find the node before the node which is to be deleted, hence the condition.
Once I arrive, I will now store the temp.next node in another local variable ptr.
Then repositioning the pointers to point to the next node.
And then returning the current node (temp)

- **What actually happened:**

Not fully mentioned: "in delete while(temp.next.self.value != self.value): AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'self'"

Please help me to find my mistakes and help me write the code more efficiently.

P.S.: I am from a C/C++ background and just started Python, so please forgive me if I have accidentally applied my concepts here. I highly appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Right, it's just `temp.next.value`.  `self is just a local variable in the function.  And there's no `self.value` -- it's just `value`.'

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have two classes: one (maybe named `Node`) that defines attributes `value` and `next`, and one (maybe named `LinkedList`) that defines an attribute `head`. There is no attribute that is called `self`. `self` is the name used for the first parameter, and refers to the "current" instance, much like `this` in other languages, but where it isn't listed as a parameter.

In your code `temp.next` is a expected to be a node reference, i.e. with its own `value` and `next` attributes. It doesn't have a `self` attribute. So remove that.

Some other remarks:

- Similarly, `value.self` is not correct. The parameter `value` is really just a "value", not a node instance. So your code should make the comparisons directly with `value` not with `value.self`
- Your code lacks a stop condition: before accessing `temp.next.value` you should first make sure that `temp` is maybe the last node in the list so that `temp.next` would be `None` and `temp.next.value` would be an invalid reference.
- The list could be empty, and then `temp.next` is an invalid reference.
- There is no code that checks whether maybe the *first* node in the list has the value that needs to be deleted. If the head node is going to be deleted, then you need to update the `self.head` attribute so it no longer references that deleted node, but the one after it.
- As you have maybe already found out, when node's are no longer referenced, there is no need to explicitly free their memory. This is managed outside of your code by the garbage collector. So there is nothing like the statement you had in a comment ("delete ptr")
- `return temp` seems not very useful. This would return the node that preceded the deleted node. I would suggest not returning anything. Or, you could return a boolean to indicate whether a node was deleted or not.

Corrected:

```
    def delete(self, value):
        """Delete the first node with a given value."""
        if self.head is None:  # A boundary case...
            return False  # Nothing to do: the list is empty
        if self.head.value == value:  # Another boundary case...
            self.head = self.head.next  # Remove the very first node
            return True  # A node was deleted
        temp = self.head
        while temp.next is not None:
            if temp.next.value == value:  # Something to delete!
                temp.next = temp.next.next
                return True  # A node was deleted
            temp = temp.next
        return False  # Nothing was deleted
```